# How to construct multipart form-data request with [String: Any] parameters

Tags: ios, swift, post, multipartform-data

I've found this code https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/URLSessionMPFD which constructs `multipart form-data` but this works when parameters are `[String: String]`. My parameters are `[String: Any]`. How to make it with `[String: Any]`?

I'm shown only relevant code, I hope it will be sufficient to understand my issue.

```
typealias Parameters = [String: String]

func construct() {
    //let parameters = ["name": "MyTestFile123321","description": "My tutorial test file for MPFD uploads"]

    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
            "APIKey":apiKey,"accessToken":accessToken,
            "user":["email":emailTextField.text!],
            "profile":["name":nameTextField.text!,"dob":dateOfBirthTextField.text!
        ]

    let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)

}
func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let lineBreak = "\r\n"
    var body = Data()

    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
        }
    }

    if let media = media {
        for photo in media {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            //...
        }
    }

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried using below parameter in that github project which mentioned by you.

```
 // Try using this modified parameter in github project
  let parameters = ["user": ["name": "MyTestFile123321",
                               "description": "My tutorial test file for MPFD uploads"],"profile": ["title": "This is big title"]] as [String : Any]
```

I have update code with `[String:Any]`

```
typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

func construct() {

    // Change it with it your parameter

     let parameters = ["user": ["name": "MyTestFile123321",
                               "description": "My tutorial test file for MPFD uploads"],"profile": ["title": "This is big title"]] as [String : Any]

     let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)

}
func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let lineBreak = "\r\n"
    var body = Data()

      if let parameters = params {

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            if let sValue = value as? String {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append("\(sValue + lineBreak)")
            }else{
                if let dictionaryObj = value as? [String : String] {
                    for (key, value) in dictionaryObj {
                        body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                        body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }

    if let media = media {
        for photo in media {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            //...
        }
    }

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you. :)

Comment: It does work but how do I test if it really does the job? I'm trying to print data but it just dumps hex values.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. "if let dictionaryObj = value as? [String : String] {" doesn't execute.

Comment: I've following format of params. It seems the first one in the else condition for key=profile is not executed while second one with key=user is executed

let json: [String : Any] = [
"APIKey":key,
"user":["email":email],
"profile":["name":name,"dob":dob]
]

Comment: This is managed as per your question like object and its subject not for object > subobj> subobj.

Comment: The structure is same as you have used in your code above. There are two subobjs "user" and "profile" as you can see in structure above. It executes for "user" but not for "profile". "if let dictionaryObj = value as? [String : String] {" is not executed for "profile" obj in the loop. What could be the reason?

Comment: I have modified my dictionary object and call api its working fine. I don't no why it doesn't work in your code I think there might be some other issue. And I will update my code according.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I've Int value in one parameter. I've tweaked code as per my need. Tx

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below, though you'd better to confirm if your server-side framework can handle this type of parameter 'name[key]'. Many of modern frameworks can.

related: [How do I POST an array with multipart/form-data encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002821/how-do-i-post-an-array-with-multipart-form-data-encoding)

```
    let parameters: [String : String] = [
        "APIKey":apiKey,
        "accessToken":accessToken,
        "user[email]":emailTextField.text!,
        "profile[name]":nameTextField.text!,
        "profile[dob]":dateOfBirthTextField.text!
    ]
```